# Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy while running a flutter project

Tags: flutter, gradle

while running a new flutter app for the first time, I get this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':gradle:detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/?.?.??/groovy-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/?.?.??/groovy-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-ant/?.?.??/groovy-ant-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-ant/?.?.??/groovy-ant-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-astbuilder:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-astbuilder/?.?.??/groovy-astbuilder-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-astbuilder/?.?.??/groovy-astbuilder-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-console:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-console/?.?.??/groovy-console-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-console/?.?.??/groovy-console-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-datetime:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-datetime/?.?.??/groovy-datetime-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-datetime/?.?.??/groovy-datetime-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-dateutil/?.?.??/groovy-dateutil-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-dateutil/?.?.??/groovy-dateutil-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-nio:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-nio/?.?.??/groovy-nio-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-nio/?.?.??/groovy-nio-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-sql/?.?.??/groovy-sql-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-sql/?.?.??/groovy-sql-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-test/?.?.??/groovy-test-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-test/?.?.??/groovy-test-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-templates/?.?.??/groovy-templates-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-templates/?.?.??/groovy-templates-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-json/?.?.??/groovy-json-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-json/?.?.??/groovy-json-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-xml/?.?.??/groovy-xml-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-xml/?.?.??/groovy-xml-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-groovydoc:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-groovydoc/?.?.??/groovy-groovydoc-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-groovydoc/?.?.??/groovy-groovydoc-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I don't know what causing the problem, I tried deleting the Flutter SDK and reinstalling it, but same issue happend.
I have no issues in my Flutter Doctor command response.
I found a closed problem about this issue on GitHub here but no solutions were givin:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/134241

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing Windows display language from Arabic to English.
After that, I restarted my system and ran the project again.